# Read USB interrupt data

Tags: c#, .net, usb, libusb

I have a USB device which which uses the libusb WIN32 drivers and

> Interrupt data is available from the
>   accelerometer through the USB-HID
>   interface endpoint 83 (in EP83). Data
>   is in little end-in format with the
>   following fields (x,y,z,Vbat,CpuTemp.)
>   Data are acquired every 62.5ms (16Hz).
>   There a number of USB HID "get" and
>   "set" Reports available (through ep0)

How can I access this data via .NET and C#?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libusb?

Comment: @John, what is your picture of?  Looks Eastern

Comment: @Inuyasha: It's from a (cancelled) TV Series. I understand that it means something like "Serenity", or "Peace of mind".

Answer (score 0):

libusb32 is c/c++ library of generic usb driver. it comes in 2 layers. low layer in kernel mode is generic client driver libusb0.sys + .inf file that you change and it tells to what device to upload this generic usb driver.They have inf-wizard.exe tool that helps for you to make this .inf file for your device. Upper layer in user space is libusb.lib (you can make also static link) that talks to libusb driver. You can find in sources usb.h that actually defines interface between you code and usb (usb driver). To access unmanaged code or you should write your layer of interop in c#  or in c++/cli or use ready layer that been made by somebody. Here the link to one of the projects, http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusbdotnet/
How to use libusb library i advice you to see some example from them. Usually it like you open handle to usb bus, then find there your device by VendorId & ProductId, get it's handle. Then make write/read to endpoints of device.

Answer (score 0):

If it is HID device I recommend you to use Windows's default driver - hid.dll, I used it and it was ok. This way you should not care about deploying also a driver, it's there anyway and you just have to understand the API and use it. For this I recommend you Jan Axelson book [USB Complete](http://www.lvr.com/usbc.htm), she has pretty good explanation and samples there, it is a mixture of C/C++ and C# but the trend is for .net Also she has a [HID Page](http://www.lvr.com/hidpage.htm) on her website and there you find the code samples you just need.